# *++argv[1] in C. What does it mean?

Tags: c, pointers

What will be the output of the program (myprog.c) given below if it is executed from the command line?

```
cmd> myprog friday tuesday sunday

/* myprog.c */ 
#include<stdio.h> 

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{ printf("%c", *++argv[1]); return 0; }
```

I understand argv[1] will be friday and ++argv[1] means tuesday. I might be wrong.
Either way, I don't seem to understand what will be the meaning of the whole expression.

Comment: @SteveCox `argv[1]` is `friday`, so isn't `++argv[1]` `riday`, thus `*++argv[1]` `r` ?

Comment: yes the answer is r but I do not understand how.
Doesn't ++argv mean next argument ?

Comment: @Kritika Jalan You are thinking of *argv[++1]

Comment: What would ++argv mean ?

Comment: Since `argv` initially points to `"myprog"`, `++argv` would 'move' the `argv` pointer to point to `"friday"` (the C runtime will have set up an array of char pointers that has the `"myprog"` pointer in the first element). However, due to operator precedence rules, in the expression `*++argv[1]` the `++` operator is applied to `argv[1]` not `argv`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Following [operator precedence rules](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence), the expression is equivalent to `*(++(argv[1]))`. In other words, `argv[1]` is evaluated first, which references the string `"friday"`. Next, the `++` prefix increment changes the reference to the string `"riday"`. Finally, the `*` dereference returns the character `'r'`.

Answer (score 9):

```
------------------------------
| f | r | i | d | a | y | \0 |
------------------------------
 ^    ^
 |    |
 |    ++argv[1]
 |
 argv[1]
```

Ergo, `*++argv[1]` gives you the character `++argv[1]` points to, which is `'r'`. [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0fd8fcd644e17489).

Answer (score 5):

> What will be the output of the program (myprog.c) given below if it is executed from the command line?

It is terribly hard to learn programming without access to a computer with a compiler on it. What did it output when you executed the program?

Anyway...

- `argv[0]` is a pointer to a string containing the program name and the following arguments are pointers to the other command line parameters.
- So `argv[1]` is a pointer pointing to the string `"friday"`, or rather to the first element `'f'`.
- `++argv[1]` increments this pointer by 1, making it point at `'r'` instead. (Btw that code line is bad practice and poor programming style. Not only because it is hard to read, but also because it is generally a bad idea to alter the command line parameters.)
- Taking the contents of the pointer should therefore give you `'r'`.

Comment: The C99 standard does not guarantee that `argv[1]` is modifiable (it does guarantee that `argv` and `argv[x][y]` are modifiable).

Comment: @MattMcNabb No. The standard states that argv should be an array of non-constant pointers. So the pointer argv[1] will always be modifiable. The C standard actually explicitly states that they _shall_ be modifiable, as shall their contents, C11 5.1.2.2.1/2: `"The parameters argc and argv and the strings pointed to by the argv array shall be modifiable by the program, and retain their last-stored values between program startup and program termination."` Same text can be found in C99.

Comment: `argv[1]` is none of "The parameters argc and argv and the strings pointed to by the argv array"

Comment: @MattMcNabb But the pointer table is a local variable, which you can modify, as it was not declared as const. Otherwise the declaration would have been `char* const argv[]`. The statement in the standard about argv has to apply to the whole pointer table, or the standard wouldn't make any sense.

Comment: "not being declared as const" is no guarantee of writability, e.g. string literals. `argv[1]` is not a local variable. `argv` is but it will point to something that may not be local to `main`.   I don't see how you construe "the strings pointed to" as meaning "the pointers and the string pointed to".

Comment: @MattMcNabb There is no other way you can interpret the standard, which makes sense. "The parameters argc and **argv**... **shall be modifiable by the program**". How would you otherwise interpret it? As if you are only free to change where argv points at, like `argv = la_la_land;`? Why on earth would you want to do that?

Comment: It's what it says that matters, not what you think it should say ... "The parameter argv" just means `argv`, it is the same as how `void f(int *const x)` means "The parameter `x` is not modifiable". You can still modify the things it points to.